# Medium.js editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Medium.js (http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/) to handle contenteditables.

My problem is following:

In the contenteditable i have some media elements (videos,images,maps) wrapped with figure. These elements are on the left side of the contenteditable. When i want to write something on the right side of an media element, there is just no Paragraph - and no paragraph is created. So i can not write there.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="itemBlocks" contenteditable="true">
    <figure class="mediaElement" contenteditable="false">     
    </figure>
</div>
```

editor:

```
 new Medium({
    element: document.getElementById('itemBlocks'),
    modifier: 'auto',
    placeholder: "Your text",
    autofocus: true,
    autoHR: true,
    mode: MediumEditor.richMode,
    maxLength: -1,
    modifiers: {
        'b': 'bold',
        'i': 'italicize',
        'u': 'underline',
        'v': 'paste'
    },
    tags: {
        'break': 'br',
        'paragraph': 'p',
        'outerLevel': ['pre', 'blockquote', 'figure', 'div'],
        'innerLevel': ['a', 'b', 'u', 'i', 'img', 'strong', 'div', 'button']
    },
    cssClasses: {
        editor: 'Medium',
        pasteHook: 'Medium-paste-hook',
        placeholder: 'Medium-placeholder',
        clear: 'Medium-clear'
    },
    attributes: {
        remove: [],
    },
    pasteAsText: true,           
});
```

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT:

I created a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wm4dn947/10/

In this case i just set a p Element under the figure Element. But the problem remains, that the figure gets destroyed and that the Medium.js is not creating automatically a new p Element.

Comment: I'm doing something similar: two figures for images, one div for text. I made the text div a sibling of the figures and wrapped them in another div that controls the layout through css. The text div is the only contenteditable and handles only text. You are probably making it harder on yourself otherwise, because the contenteditable has to handle additional kinds of block-level items, which mean you have to extend medium.js to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Ah i had really tough times with medium.js. It just doesn't offer this functionality. I decided to try another editor - froala. And i can really recommend it to you. Unbelievable great written - great docs and super easy to handle. Also the customization options are really good!